# SharedPreferences on a non-Activity extended class

Tags: java, android

I have a class that sends some info to the mysql db.
I want from this class to use the Shared Preferences methods but they are belong to the activity class.
My class extends AsyncTask so I can't extend another.. I tried to create an activity instance and use it but my program has stoped. something like this:

```
Activity a1 = new Activity();
SharedPreferenecs loginInfo = a1.getSharedPreferences("MyKid", 0);
```

etc ..

Comment: pass the `Context` in non `Activity` class. and then use `mContext.getSharedPreferences("MyKid", 0); `

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but pass the Context instance from where?I speaked about one class only.

Comment: pass `Context` in the `Constructor` of your `non Activity` class. there put a member `private Context mContext;` and init in constructor.

Comment: Now I understand, but how can I do that if I call the non activity class through a View.OnClickListener() block? 'this' recognized as View.OnClickListener();

Comment: pass `yourActivityName.this` :)

Comment: Thank you so much! post it as an answer and I will accept it. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the Context of your `Activity` in non Activity class's Constructor.

and then use

```
mContext.getSharedPreferences("MyKid", 0);
```